# Why does my Swift get build error: No exact matches in call to instance method 'append'

Tags: swift, xcode

Can't figure out what's wrong.

```
struct Ring_Sensors_Input_struct
{
    var ts: Double
    var temp: UInt16       
    var hr: UInt8          

    var spO2: UInt8        
    var rr: UInt8          
    var steps: UInt16

    init(        ts: Double,
                    temp: UInt16,
                    hr: UInt8,
                    spO2: UInt8,
                    rr: UInt8,
                    steps: UInt16 )
    {
        self.ts = ts
        self.temp = temp
        self.hr = hr
        self.spO2 = spO2
        self.rr = rr
        self.steps = steps
    }
}

func my_func()
{
    var ring_sensors_input: [Ring_Sensors_Input_struct] = []
    ring_sensors_input.append( ts: 1657150485.0, temp: 235, hr: 95, spO2: 97, rr: 16, steps: 235 ) <<<<<<<<< ERROR: No exact matches in call to instance method 'append'
    ring_sensors_input.append( ts: 1657150486.0, temp: 238, hr: 92, spO2: 98, rr: 14, steps: 238 ) <<<<<<<<< ERROR: No exact matches in call to instance method 'append'
}
```

Comment: You are not calling the init of `Ring_Sensors_Input_struct`, try `ring_sensors_input.append(.init(ts: 16....`

Comment: You create wrong object. you can do this. ring_sensors_input.append(Ring_Sensors_Input_struct(ts: 1657150485.0, temp: 235, hr: 95, spO2: 97, rr: 16, steps: 235) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your code by:

```
func my_func() {
   var ring_sensors_input: [Ring_Sensors_Input_struct] = []
   ring_sensors_input.append(Ring_Sensors_Input_struct(ts:1657150485.0, temp: 235, hr: 95, spO2: 97, rr: 16, steps: 235))
   ring_sensors_input.append(Ring_Sensors_Input_struct(ts: 1657150486.0, temp: 238, hr: 92, spO2: 98, rr: 14, steps: 238))
}
```

The problem is if you want to append an object, like your structure, you have to call it inside the append method. If you don't, the code doesn't know what you are trying to add.